# running data forEach in js with jquery and it is not executing each item in a switch

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code I attempt to loop over a storage object and if the case matches it should add a class to the element:

```
    const localData = {
    Direction: "1",
    Lamination: "3",
    Stock: "10",
    exit_popup: "true",
    job_name: "test",
    length: 8,
    prod-height: "3",
    prod-width: "2",
    slct: "2",
}

function checkPrevInputs(localData) {
console.log('running');
console.log(localData);
  Object.keys(localData).forEach((item, i) => {
    switch (item) {
      case 'job_name':
        $('#job_name').val(localData[item]);
        break;
      case 'prod-height':
        $('#prod-height').val(localData[item]);
        break;
      case 'prod-width':
        $('#prod-width').val(localData[item]);
        break;
      case 'slct':
        $('#slct').val(localData[item]);
        break;
      case 'Stock':
        const elStock = $(`.el-selection[data-type="Stock"][data-id="${localData[item]}"]`);
        elStock.addClass('selectedBtnOption');
        elStock.prev('.tab-navigation').addClass('selection-made');
        break;
      case 'Lamination':
        const elLamination = $(`.el-selection[data-type="Lamination"][data-id="${localData[item]}"]`);
        elLamination.addClass('selectedBtnOption');
        elLamination.prev('.tab-navigation').addClass('testingaddition');
        break;
      case 'Direction':
        const elDirection = $(`.el-selection[data-type="Direction"][data-id="${localData[item]}"]`);
        elDirection.addClass('selectedBtnOption');
        elDirection.prev('.tab-navigation').addClass('selection-made');
        break;
      default:

    }
  });

}
```

In the following HTML the class was not added even thou Lamination is in the object which gets looped and it appears in the dom:

```
<div class="tab-navigation" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                              <button class="btn btn-solid navigate" value="2">
                                                  Previous
                                              </button>
                                              <button class="btn btn-solid navigate" value="4">
                                                  Next
                                              </button>
                                          </div>

                                          <div class="row justify-content-md-center el-selection vertical-align" data-type="Lamination" data-id="3">
                                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                                  <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/coating/iKXG8mhCIW5q5YoKp8YXplZmUeSIydldZvZ3ldQk.svg" alt="" class="w-100 img-fluid blur-up lazyload image_zoom_cls-0">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                  <h6 class="product-title">Gloss Lamination</h6>
                                                  <button class="btn btn-outline btn-sm detailsToggle">Show me details</button>
                                                </div>
                                                                                                  <div class="col-md-3">
                                                    <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/images/icon/popular.svg" alt="" class="w-100 img-fluid blur-up lazyload image_zoom_cls-0">
                                                  </div>
                                                                                            </div>
```

You can see I have: data-type="Lamination" but the prev .tab-navigation doesn't seem to be triggered.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can we assume your `const localData = {` properties all have commas after them?

Comment: yes let me correct, I copied that from the console.log. @Kinglish

Comment: Your code seems ok to me .Can you replicate that behaviour by making [mcve] ?

Answer (score 0):

Jquery can't find your  element because you've set up `Lamination: "3"` in the localData obj and `data-id="2"` in the HTML markup.

Other than that the code works correctly.[image]

Comment: I fixed that, but there are several data-id about 6 but I can see where it was caught as the issue.

Comment: I ran your code with correct datatype locally and it works fine.

Comment: The only issue was in that snippet: 
`[data-id="${localData[item]}"]`

Comment: I think the issue is with the loop because it doesn't get each element is what I was saying.